# When merging two queries in Power BI, can I exact match on one key and fuzzy match on a second key?

Tags: merge, powerbi

I am merging two tables in Power BI where I want to have an exact match on one field, then a fuzzy match on a second field.

In the example below, I want for there to be an exact match for the "Key" columns in Table 1 and Table 2. In table 2, the "Key" column is not a unique identifier and can have multiple names associated with a key. So, I want to then fuzzy match on the name column. Is there a way to do this in Power BI?

Table 1

| Key | Name1 | info_a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Michael | a |
| 2 | Robert | b |

Table 2

| Key | Name2 | info_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | aa |
| 1 | Andrea | cc |
| 2 | Robbie | bb |
| 2 | Michelle | dd |

Result

| Key | Name1 | Name2 | info_a | info_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Michael | Mile | a | aa |
| 2 | Robert | Robbie | b | bb |

Comment: Yes you can. DAX or PQ ? If DAX, what is the relationship?

Comment: Comments from the deleted answer in response to Ron.

Fair point. I'm not 100% sure how fuzzy merge works under the covers with multiple columns. I just tested it by changing the keys to 3 and 4 and left everything else the same and got no matches. However, changing the keys to 11 and 22 did bring back matches so in summary, you're right. OP, if need exact match on key in the first instance, we'll need a different solution for you. I'll remove my original answer in the meantime. – 
David

Comment: @David Another interesting point about this issue is that I was not able to get `Mike` and `Michael` to fuzzy match, no matter where I set the threshold.  I think another method may be needed to fuzzy match names like that.

Comment: I get the same as you @RonRosenfeld. The only way I can think to achieve this is using fuzzy match with a transformation table for instances like Mike/Michael. Interestingly, I read here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-fuzzy-match-power-query-ffdd5082-c0c8-4c8e-a794-bd3962b90649 that for the similarity threshold: "The minimum value of 0.00 causes all values to match each other. " I think this is a documentation mistake as it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a Python script to solve this problem.

I merged Table 1 and Table 2 on the field ("Key") where an exact match was required.

Then I added this Python script:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def get_fuzz_score(
    df: pd.DataFrame, col1: str, col2: str, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio
) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    df: pd.DataFrame
    col1: str, name of column from df
    col2: str, name of column from df
    scorer: fuzzywuzzy scorer (e.g. fuzz.ratio, fuzz.Wratio, fuzz.partial_ratio, fuzz.token_sort_ratio)

    Returns
    -------
    scores: pd.Series

    """
    scores = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if row[col1]in [np.nan, None] or row[col2] in [np.nan, None]:
            scores.append(None)
        else:
            scores.append(scorer(row[col1], row[col2]))
    return scores

dataset['fuzzy_score'] = get_fuzz_score(dataset, 'Name1', 'Name2', fuzz.WRatio)
dataset['MatchRank'] = dataset.groupby(['Key'])['fuzzy_score'].rank('first', ascending=False)
```

Then I could just consider the matches where MatchRank = 1